# How to remove white-space from the bottom of footer

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

There is some content that I need to include in my footer.

The footer normally is not able to accommodate all this informatuion and I ends up rendering the content outside of the bounds of the footer like so:

---

[image]

---

My first idea was to increase the size of the footer, but after many attempts at changing the `.footer`, `.modal-footer`, and many other things in a seperate css file within the assets folder, nothing worked.

My next idea was to create a bespoke footer and collapse the default footer like so:

```
<footer class="text-muted well" id="last-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <p class="footer-text text-muted text-center">

                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZjO4e.png" alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42">
                <br>
                <a href="http://www.kigroup.de/impressum.html" class="text-center">
                    Kontakt | Impressum | Datenschutz
                </a>

                <span class="pull-left">
                    <a href="about.html#drop_us_a_line">Contact Us</a>
                </span>

                <span class="pull-right">
                    {{addYear '©'}}
                </span>

            </p>

        </div>
</footer>

<!-- begin: default footer -->
<div class="footer collapse">
</div>
<!-- end: default footer -->
```

but this creates a bunch of ugly whitespace under the footer like so:

---

[image]

---

ultimately what I want is a footer like in the second picture but without all that white space underneath it- ideally in a way that is maintainable in the future and ameanable to swaping in and out other bootstrap templates- so... any ideas?

Comment: can you share a fiddle ? Try using overflow: auto css rule to #last-footer. It is better to share a working fiddle

Comment: does it make sense to create a fiddle? the problem is not the code it'self but the bootstrap framework, is it feasible to include bootstrap in a fiddle?

Comment: Of course. Have you tried with the overflow: auto ?

Comment: I put the solutuion below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how to remove white-space from the bottom of footer

```
body {
  padding-bottom: 0px !important;
  margin-bottom: -40px !important;
}
footer.well{
  margin-bottom: -20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to your site.css and remove this

```
-body {
-  /* Margin bottom by footer height */
-  margin-bottom: 60px;
-}
```

Your site.css should be in wwwroot/css folder.